# how to get emacs24 to highlight PHP

Tags: php, emacs

Any emacs veterans able to assist?

I can not find the files that the various websites that claim to show you how to obtain or make the settings for emacs24 to highlight PHP.

I read contradicting information that some members of the team who developed the highlighting for php are refusing to sign the paperwork (I am assuming making it copy-left)

Some alternatives look like they exist, I did find some files but I can not edit them as they are read only.

PHP mode for emacs sends me to a sourceforge site and the development is for windows...

I found this http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/php-mode-improved.el and would like to try it, so I found the `/etc/emacs24` folder and made a file where other `.el` files existed and wasn't able to paste in the data from that link's download, the emacs24 moans about the file being read only and when I try to quit I am stuck in a save dialog.

Where do I stick it? Then what do I need to do next as it is not entirely clear.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I ran

```
apt-cache search php |grep -i emacs
```

which shows

```
php-elisp - Emacs support for php files
```

and after

```
sudo apt-get install php-elisp
```

emacs shows a php file quite colorful.

Comment: I do not know why this does not work for me (emacs 26, Ubuntu 16)

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ: [`(use-package php-mode
  :ensure t)`](https://github.com/emacs-php/php-mode) works for me on Emacs 26.1 on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I followed this method, and it worked for me, even if the listed package was *elpa-php-mode*. Installing *phps-mode*, the package listed from Emacs, didn't automatically highlighted PHP code, while *elpa-php-mode* worked out-of-the-box. I am using Linux Lite 5.4 as distribution; that could explain the different deb package I found with `apt-cache search php | grep -i emacs`.